# How do I change the label in a data step header?

Tags: sas

In SAS you can do.

```
data a(rename=(a=b) );
  a = 1;
run;
```

to rename a variable in the data step data statement (or data step header as I call it).

What's the syntax to change the label? I tried

```
data a(label=(a='a to b') );
  a = 1;
run;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data a;
    x=1;
    label x="label"; * original label;
run;

proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    modify a;
    label x='new label';
run; quit;
```

Comment: Even though you can't do it in the data step header. The reason why I wanted to do it in the datastep header is to save a cycle of IO. The proc datasets methods seems to be able to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think manipulating label via data step options is possible. For manipulating label using data step, either one is fine:

```
attrib a label='a to b';
label a='a to b';
```

but I guess you already knew.